# request.session in different views using curl

Tags: django, curl, django-rest-framework, axios, postman

I have a backend built with Django.

Problem:-
I am sending phone number via POST and storing in session via `request.session['phone_number']` in one view and trying to get the same in another view but facing **Key Error**

What could be the issue?

Also via **Postman** its working fine but via **curl** or **axios** I'm getting this error.

Comment: Can you share how you made the request with `curl`?

Comment: curl -X POST https://demo.appspot.com/verify/ -d "phone_number=9191XXXXXXXX"